# Bluetooth and Wifi Maximum Power limt

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, fcc, certification, ce

I saw below Bluetooth chip comparison of many module , most of all are having 8dbm max power ,  what  I know FCC has 30dbm and CE has 20dbm Max power limit so why Bluetooth module are limited to only 8dbm Power. Do Bluetooth have different limit for power or else.

Sine Most of Wifi chip comes with max power +20 dbm may be due to CE limit. so why not Bluetooth module comes with 20 dbm so we can get more range?

Comment: Have you got a bluetooth application that requires more range? It's "dB" and not db.

Comment: Outdoor application require 80-100 meter range , but  what datasheet claim is LOS , so if we can get around 500 m LOS with higher power than in practical world 100 m can be possible

Comment: There's the old class 1, 2, 3 Bluetooth which respectively had 20dBm, 4dBm and 0dBm maximum E.R.P. Then BLE which apparently can go up to 10dBm maximum. So I'm not sure where you got your numbers from. And if you wanna know the reasons why: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_absorption_rate. Ain't too sexy to walk around with a 20dBm headset close to your ear/brain.